# TFS: recursively list local files

Tags: tfs

How do I recursively list all local files in my mapped TFS folders? In other words, files not under source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/) installed, this should be possible with a
`tfpt scorch /noprompt /preview`

Comment: The "exclude" option is also useful, for example `tfpt scorch /noprompt /preview /exclude:bin,obj,*.suo,*.csproj.user`